# Javafx and combobox

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, combobox

I have an int variable (modID) from a selected tablecolumn. I would like to use this variable to search a two column combobox (int modelID, String model), match the modelID column of the combobox and display the corresponding model value.

Class used to construct the combobox.

```
package batteryOrdering.order;

public class ModelList {
    private int modelID;
    private int manufacturerID;
    private String model;

    public ModelList(int modelID, String model) {
        this.modelID = modelID;
        this.manufacturerID = manufacturerID;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getModelID() {
        return modelID;
    }

    public int getManufacturerID() {
        return manufacturerID;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }
}
```

The following code matches against the combobox index and not the ID column. What is wrong?

```
modelCombobox.getSelectionModel().select(modID);
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to have ~20 columns to ask this question?

Comment: did you read the help page? if so, why don't you provide an mcve as described? without, your question is not answerable and most probably will be closed ..

Comment: Sorry, made the necessary changes to the original post.